# Socket Testing Software like GuiltFTP

Tags: software-development

During development of FTP client we used GuiltFTP to configure in local PC with minimal steps. It acts as a FTP server in a local machine and all FTP commands are tested.

Similarly we need to develop Socket Server testing.

Is there is any freeware or open source which acts as Socket Server and able to send us responses for our requests???

Thanks.

Comment: "Socket server" could be virtually anything. If you're using a custom protocol, you'll need to develop the server part yourself. Otherwise, specify the exact protocol you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this: https://github.com/timgold81/honeypot
It opens a socket server at any port number you want, sends something and logs anything you send to it

Comment: Need to have few request and response as well...It is possible..Like Commands or any request other than just login...Any other request and response. Please help me out

Comment: I come across this https://github.com/akshath/SocketTest/blob/master/dist/SocketTest.jar. However it is not sending any response back.

Comment: I have already gone through the following but not useful - </br> https://github.com/Serega290696/simple_client_server_socket/blob/master/src/Server.java  </br> 

https://github.com/spurcell999/Socket  </br> 

https://github.com/ClicSistemas/VirtualSocket  </br> 

https://github.com/akshath/SocketTest/blob/master/dist/SocketTest.jar  </br>

Comment: How about changing the code of the link I provided to you need?

Comment: It would be time consuming..Instead do you suggest any tool which can be customizable as per our testing requirement..request and response

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you need a specific one for each service. "it acts like a local ftp server"  It may be easiest to run a virtual box and put the OS of your choice on it and run actual servers on it.

Now if you need to see the exchange that happens, look at netcat -- it's a generalized network 'pipe fitting' that can be used for all kinds of stuff where something happening on one machine and talking to another.

Comment: the keys are already expired and it is not an active project. can u pls suggest like netcat